# Finding a certain shape in grid

Tags: java, algorithm, grid, shapes

I have a 2 Dimensional array as a grid (9x9 in size) and want to find a couple of specific shapes in it:

```
XXX XXX  X
 X  X   XXX
 X  X    X
```

AFTER i searched for these and removed them from the grid i want to search for 3/4/5-long straight lines. NOTE: All elements of this shape have to have the same color.

Obviously i could just hardcode these in or bruteforce my way to finding those but I'm looking for an algorithm which finds those shapes in a feasable time.

This is my code for finding and removing the straight lines. As the output i expect the amount of elements that have been removed in the process. It works (most of the time... bonus points if you can tell me how to combine horizontal/vertical in one, but thats a topic for another day):

```
private Cell[][] field;

/**
 * Removes a given list of stones from the field and 
 * fills the slots with empty ones.
 * 
 * @param list 
 */
private void removeStones(ArrayList<int[]> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        field[list.get(i)[1]][list.get(i)[0]] = new Cell(Color.NONE, Attribute.NONE);
    }
}

/**
 * Check the gamefield for valid straight structures and remove them.
 * 
 * @return The amount of stones removed.
 */
private int checkStraight() {
    Color curr = Color.NONE;
    int counter = 0;
    int total = 0;
    /* Holds the coordinates of the shape being processed currently */
    ArrayList<int[]> stones = new ArrayList<>();

    // Horizontal 
    for(int y = 0; y < getSize(); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < getSize(); x++) {
            if(curr == getCell(x, y).getBlock().getColor() 
                    && getCell(x, y).isGem()) {
                counter++;
                stones.add(new int[] {x, y});
            }             
            else {
                if(counter > 2) {
                    total += counter;
                    removeStones(stones);
                    /* Debugging Info */
                    stones.forEach((a)->System.out.println("[" + a[0] + "," + a[1] + "]"));
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                counter = 1;
                curr = getCell(x, y).getBlock().getColor();
                stones = new ArrayList<>();
                stones.add(new int[] {x, y});
            }
        }
        curr = Color.NONE;
        counter = 0;
    }

    // Vertical
    for(int x = 0; x < getSize(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < getSize(); y++) {
            if(curr == getCell(x, y).getBlock().getColor() 
                    && getCell(x, y).isGem()) {
                counter++;
                stones.add(new int[] {x, y});
            }             
            else {
                if(counter > 2) {
                    total += counter;
                    removeStones(stones);
                    /* Debugging Info */
                    stones.forEach((a)->System.out.println("[" + a[0] + "," + a[1] + "]"));
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                counter = 1;
                curr = getCell(x, y).getBlock().getColor();
                stones = new ArrayList<>();
                stones.add(new int[] {x, y});
            }
        }
        curr = Color.NONE;
        counter = 0;
    }

    return total;
}

/**
 * Return cell at col/row.
 *
 * @param col
 * @param row
 * @return The cell at position col/row.
 */
public Cell getCell( int col, int row ) {
    return field[row][col];
}

/**
 * Return the grid size.
 *
 * @return The size of the grid.
 */
public int getSize() {
    return field.length;
}
```

If you need additional info about the structure of cells or clarification about how something is supposed to work exactly just ask and i will provide more info.

Comment: Please add what removeStones and getSize do, as well as how stones is initialized. You are missing removing lines where they end at getSize(), you can actually add to counter from different lines with your code

Comment: Alright, i added the functions you asked for. I'm not sure what you mean with the stones initialization. It is a local variable in checkStraight() and initialized there.

Comment: consider a whole line of same color with all gems, your code does not remove it

Comment: Ahh i see what you mean, didn't encounter this yet but you are right. I have to treat that case individually.

Comment: Well it doesnt need to be a whole line, just needs to be a line that ends at the border of the board. As for it doesn't work at apparently random occasions, need a case where it doesn´t

Comment: At least that probably fixes the issue i was having where sometimes lines weren't disappearing. Just the problem finding specific structures remains.

Comment: A simple way is for every cell, try to match the shape. Complexity would be O(n * n * amount of cells in shape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles over the same question as i did i wanted to share how i solved this in the end.

I made a function that looks for a given shape (In my case i always needed to check for 5 positions in a 3x3 square but you could adjust it any way you want), then compares the resulting pattern to the content of the grid and return the found positions

This function is then called 4 times to find an 'L-Shape' by inputting the base L-Shape in any rotation to find it at a given position.

```
/**
* Find the structure specified in p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5 rotated by 90
* degrees rot times
*
* @param x   X-Position of the structure
* @param y   Y-Position of the structure
* @param rot How many times to rotate by 90 degrees
* @param p1  A piece of the structure (Coordinates)
* @param p2  A piece of the structure (Coordinates)
* @param p3  A piece of the structure (Coordinates)
* @param p4  A piece of the structure (Coordinates)
* @param p5  A piece of the structure (Coordinates)
* @return The ArrayList containing all found stones
*/
private ArrayList<int[]> findStructure( int x, int y, int rot, int[] p1, int[] p2, int[] p3, int[] p4, int[] p5 ) {
    ArrayList<int[]> stones = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Rotate shape by 90 degrees rot times */
    for( int i = 1; i <= rot; i++ ) {
        /* Rotate 90 degress */
        p1 = new int[]{-p1[1], p1[0]};
        p2 = new int[]{-p2[1], p2[0]};
        p3 = new int[]{-p3[1], p3[0]};
        p4 = new int[]{-p4[1], p4[0]};
        p5 = new int[]{-p5[1], p5[0]};
    }

    // Do stuff and see if your pattern matches the actual grid content
    // ...

    return stones;
}
```